# Find an operator given its eigenvectors and the first column of its matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

It is known that $a_1 (0,1,1)$,  $a_2 (1, -1,0)$  and   $a_3 (1,0, -1)$ are eigenvectors of an operator $ T $ on $ \mathbb{R} ^ 3 $, whose associated matrix regarding the canonical basis has as first column the triplet $ (1,2,3)^t$.

Find $ T $.

Comment: @copper.hat    I tried found eigenvalues but nothing, I used wolfram to help me

Comment: Let $A$ be the matrix of eigenvectors. Then $TA = A \Lambda$, where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix of eigenvalues. By setting $\Lambda = \operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)$ you can figure out the values of $\lambda_k$ to get the requisite first column.

Comment: @copper.hat     thanks I have this eigenvalues (0,6,2) then
$$T=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & -1 & 1 \\
2 &  4 & 2 \\
3 & 3  & 3 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 1):

A)$\begin{bmatrix} 1&a&b\\ 2&c&d\\3&e&f \end{bmatrix}*\begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 1 \\1\end{bmatrix}
=\lambda_1 *\begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 1\\1 \end{bmatrix}
$ $\to$ $a=b $  and   $  c+d=e+f$

B)$\begin{bmatrix} 1&a&b\\ 2&c&d\\3&e&f \end{bmatrix}*\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 0\\-1\end{bmatrix}=\lambda_2\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 0\\-1\end{bmatrix}$ $\to$ $d=2$ and $f-b=2$

C)$\begin{bmatrix} 1&a&b\\ 2&c&d\\3&e&f \end{bmatrix}*\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ -1\\0\end{bmatrix}=\lambda_3\begin{bmatrix} 1\\-1\\-10\end{bmatrix}$ $\to$ $e=3$ and $a+c=3$

then you have 4 equation and 4 unknown variable

Comment: Thanks for your help :D ,perfect answer :D